# What is the fastest way to initialize all elements in an array to NaN?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, memory-management, nan

In C# .NET, what is the fastest way to initialize an array of doubles to NaN?

Here is how I am presently initializing an array with many elements.

```
int length = array.Length;
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    array[i] = double.NaN;
}
```

Is there a faster way?

Comment: I like 'Enumerable.Repeat(defaulValue, arrayLength).ToArray()' (available since .NET 3.5)

Comment: If you're on Linux, memory-map [my device driver](https://github.com/njwhite/devnan) that returns copy-on-write pages filled with NaNs as an array of doubles. O(1) regardless of array size!

Answer (score 2):

Filling the array with byte values of 0xff produces NaN.  Try this code to see what is fastest on your machine.  Memset() is not always a slam-dunk btw:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program {
  static void Main(string[] args) {
    var arr = new double[10 * 1024 * 1024];
    for (int loop = 1; loop < 20; ++loop) {
      var sw1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
      for (int ix = 0; ix < arr.Length; ++ix)
        arr[ix] = double.NaN;
      sw1.Stop();
      var sw2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
      memset(arr, 0xff, 8 * arr.Length);
      sw2.Stop();
      Console.WriteLine("Loop: {0}, memset: {1}", sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds, sw2.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
  }
  [DllImport("msvcrt.dll")]
  private static extern void memset(double[] array, int value, int cnt);
}
```

Comment: I *really* wish there was an intrinsic method in C# that emitted the `initblk` opcode, or at least a static method in `mscorlib` that the JIT knew to always treat as an initblk instruction.

Comment: Did you run this code?  Don't forget to use the Release build and don't run in the debugger.  Swapping the two sections had a very interesting effect on my machine.

Comment: Was that directed to me? I was just saying `initblk` is a CIL opcode that is effectively `memset` except it avoids the P/Invoke and it's likely heavily optimized into the CLR.

Comment: Unless there is a *very* good reason for such an optimization I'd prefer the original for-loop, because of better readability, maintainability and robustness. By the way, wouldn't the use of memset require the array to be pinned? Something like `GCHandle gch = GCHandle.Alloc(arr, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    memset(gch.AddrOfPinnedObject(), 0xff, 8 * arr.Length);`

Comment: The pinvoke marshaller automatically pins arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You can multithread it, but it is still an O(N) problem.